# Android - BuildTypes get value always from debug

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have a problem when i generated signed apk.
when i generated release apk is always give me the QA value for versionName and versionCode.

**This is my defaultConfig:**

```
    def date = new Date()
    def df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMddHHmm")
    def dfName = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MM-dd")
    df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"))

    versionCode df.format(date).toInteger()
    versionName dfName.format(date)
```

**This is my buildType:**

```
    buildTypes {
    debug {
        android.defaultConfig.versionCode 1
        android.defaultConfig.versionName "1"
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
       'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}
```

for example, when i generated apk with release i get versionCode and versionName equal to 1 like its should be on QA

Comment: stop editing questions adding `Android - ` in the title. Tags don't belong in titles

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version code and version name are being evaluated when the gradle task is performed. Hence you cannot override it within the different build types, or to be correct: You override it globally each time you set it!

I think you could intercept the task and apply the desired code like this:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    if (variant.buildType.isDebuggable()) {
        variant.mergedFlavor.versionCode = 1
        variant.mergedFlavor.versionName = "1"
    }
}
```

Comment: where should it be? on build.gradle?